# Add InputBox to ask for the Recipient to be added to the "To..." box

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a VBA script that launches an Outlook Template and replaces %_% with the user's name after I input it into an InputBox.

I was wondering if there is a way to create an InputBox that requests the recipient's email address and inputs it into the "To..." box.

```
Sub TerminationsEmail()

    txtUser = InputBox("Terminated Employee's Name", "Name of Recipient")

    Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set itm = myOlApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Users\fm81996\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Asset Recovery.oft")

    itm.HTMLBody = Replace(itm.HTMLBody, "%_%", txtUser)

    itm.Display

End Sub
```

Comment: Use another [`InputBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/inputbox-function) to capture the email address, and then please have a look at the [`Outlook.MailItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-object-outlook) class, specificially the [`To`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-to-property-outlook) property.

Comment: FWIW `InputBox` makes for a rather poor UX. Its main purpose is to provide quick input *for dev/debug purposes*. You should probably implement this as a proper `UserForm`, with proper input validation. If the email is on an Active Directory domain, I'd look into how to pull the user's email from the directory given `Environ$("USERNAME")` - no prompt required.

Comment: Protip: specify `Option Explicit` at the top of the module, then declare all these local variables with a `Dim` statement. With `Dim itm As MailItem` you will get autocomplete when you type the dot in `itm.` - explore that list and you'll find a `To` property. Then hit F2 and explore everything the `Outlook` library has in store for you, with particular attention to the `MailItem` class. That said, if this code is in an Outlook-VBA macro, `myOlApp` is a perfectly redundant reference to `Application`, a global-scope object you get for free. If you're not in Outlook, tag the post accordingly.

Comment: I will be brutally honest with you guys, I only started looking into VBA scripting today and I'm not the best. What I was wonderiong was that I can make another InputBox as Mathieu suggested, but how do I make the connection to

`Set myRecipient = myItem.Recipients.Add("Recipient's name goes here")`

Per say
@DavidZemens
@MathieuGuindon

Comment: quick and dirty: `Dim myRecipient as Recipient ' or As Object, using Late-binding` and then `Set myRecipient = myItem.Recipients.Add(InputBox("prompt for user email address"))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leveraging only the `MailItem.To` property mentioned above, you can do something like (untested):

`itm.To = InputBox("prompt for user email address; modify as needed")`

Or:

```
Dim myRecipient as Recipient
Dim email as String
email = InputBox("What is the email address?")
Set myRecipient = itm.Recipients.Add(email)
```

Comment: Looks Like I'm getting closer. the line

`Set myRecipient = itm.Recipients.Add(email)`

however, throws an error 424 - Object required. What object is missing?

Comment: Can you revise your original question ([you can edit it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49699136/edit)) to include the code you're currently using?

Comment: I'm an idiot guys.

`Dim myRecipient as Recipient
Dim email as String
email = InputBox("What is the email address?")
Set myRecipient = itm.Recipients.Add(email)`

was correct. However, I was placing the code prior to 

`Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set itm = myOlApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Users\fm81996\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Asset Recovery.oft")`

It cannot input a recipient to an email that has yet not been created. 

I REALLY appreciate all you guys' help.

Answer (score 0):

Have mixed the macros which seem to work:

```
Sub TerminationsEmail()

    txtUser = InputBox("Terminated Employee's Name", "Name of Recipient")

    Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set itm = myOlApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Users\fm81996\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Asset Recovery.oft")

    itm.To = txtUser

    itm.Display

End Sub
```